# I need to retrieve RCS messages on samsung phone

Tags: java, android, sms, mms, rich-communications-services

I am using this code below to grab MMS. I read in other places that RCS was held here on my samsung galaxy phone. However, My code is not grabbing the RCS messages. It only appears to be grabbing the MMS as far as I can tell.

```
        Uri uri = Telephony.Mms.CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                Telephony.Mms.DATE,
                Telephony.Mms._ID
        };

        String selection = Telephony.Mms.DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                String.valueOf(startTime.getTime() / 1000),
                String.valueOf(endTime.getTime() / 1000)
        };
        
        String sortBy = Telephony.Mms.DATE + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortBy);
```

I am unsure what else to try. I don't usually post in here, but it just doesn't seem to be retrieving them at all so I am at a loss. There doesn't seem to be an RCS content provider for my phone, and I see other people on stack overflow saying they are stored in the mms content provider.

Comment: I haven't done any actual testing yet, but it's starting to look like that functionality is specific to Google Messages. That is, their app just happens to use the MMS Provider to store its RCS, but other apps won't necessarily do that.

Comment: I was pretty sure about that but I saw someone on here saying they tested it working on Samsung devices. I guess I'd have to be using Google Messages and not Samsung messages. Actually, I may just test that and see. If Google Messages stores RCS in the MMS provider then maybe I'll just switch.

Comment: I switched to Google Messages and I am unsure why the heck I have been using Samsung Messages for so long. Not only can I grab the messages from Google Messages using the MMS fetcher, but the interface is also much better and less buggy. Glad I switched! :)